# How to get rid of "No jax-rs activator is defined for the project" warning?

Tags: eclipse

I have a web project in my eclipse workspace, and I'm getting this annoying warning:

**No jax-rs activator is defined for the project**

I know that this is related to web-services, but I currently don't use web services on this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just make Eclipse shut up about it.

Go to the `Preferences` of your project `>` `JAX-RS Validator` `>` `JAX-RS Validator` `>` check `Enable project specific preferences`  and then `JAX-RS Activators` `>` set `No JAX-RS Activator configured` to `Ignored`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me (JBoss Developer Studio 7.1.1 GA) it was:

right-click project in Package Explorer --> **Properties** --> **Jax-RS Validator**

--> uncheck **JAX RS support:**