# What is Eclipse referring to with the warning "No JAX-RS Activator is defined for the project"

Tags: eclipse, jax-rs

Eclipse is warning "No JAX-RS Activator is defined for the project".

What does it mean?

Note: This is not a duplicate of the question [How to get rid of "No jax-rs activator is defined for the project" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086780/how-to-get-rid-of-no-jax-rs-activator-is-defined-for-the-project-warning)
- I don't necessarily want to remove it from displaying. I want to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have the JBoss tools installed.

> The [JaxRsActivator](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Web_Framework_Kit/2.5/html/Getting_Started_with_an_HTML5_Mobile_Web_Project/JaxRsActivator.java_File.html) class initializes JAX-RS without the need to use a web.xml file. This is achieved by extending the Application class and using the @ApplicationPath annotation. The value provided in the @ApplicationPath annotation defines the root path for all other JAX-RS HTTP calls.

The second answer to the linked question, which turns off the feature rather than the validation, would seem to apply.

Comment: It was because I had JAX-RS  set up in my project facets, but hadn't used the annotation mentioned. Once I started using the annotation the warning went away.